# How to configure Java velocity template engine in Eclipse?

Tags: java, velocity

I am new in Java velocity template engine. I have created a dynamic web project in  Eclipse and placed required jar files (`velocity-tools-1.4.jar` , `velocity-dep-1.4.jar`, `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar` & `commons-lang-2.3.jar`) in `WebContent --> web-inf -->` lib folder and configured my `web.xml`.

I have created a servlet and a vm file. But when I try to execute the project, I get errors. I tried with different solutions, but still get the same errors. Can anybody share me the complete steps of configuring Java velocity template engine in Eclipse?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What solutions did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Maven, then it is as easy as adding a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

At the main site of Velocity, they say:

> If you want to jumpstart your application, simply include **velocity-x.x.x.jar** in your classpath: it includes all classes of Velocity Engine (with the exclusion of the examples). Include all the jars in the "lib" subdirectory too.

Comment: you might also be missing commons-collections-3.2.1.jar or commons-lang-2.4.jar